# add aocolumns with $.parseJson() datatables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I need to fill a table with json from the server, the `aaData` and `aoColumns`, but the thing is that I need a column with a button.

I have this code

```
$('#divGrid').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

var results = result.split('@_@');
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aaData": $.parseJSON(results[0]),

    ,
    "aoColumns": $.parseJSON(results[1])
});
}
```

my results are

```
results[0] = "[["
jpa ","
SI ","
","
","
","
PADILLA ",1],["
sid ","
SI ","
","
","
","
MIRAMONTES ",2]]"

results[1] = [{
    "sTitle": "UserName"
}, {
    "sTitle": "ID_CENTRO_TRABAJO"
}, {
    "sTitle": "rolName"
}, {
    "sTitle": "dominio"
}, {
    "sTitle": "recibeAlertas"
}, {
    "sTitle": "NOMBRE"
}, {
    "sTitle": "edit",
    "fnRender": 'function(obj){ return ' < input type = 'button'
    name = 'hola'
    value = 'Play' > < /input>';}'}]"
```

but my console is clean, no errors are thrown. The value appears but the button is not.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same single quote in return and encapsulating attributes, use double quote for the attributes

```
return '<input  type="button" name="hola" value="Play">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem a bit different. Maybe this can help you.

Instead of trying to add the button directly add some kind of placeholder content to the column you want something special to be in and then modify the result during the row callback event:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aaData": [["Test", "data", "<div class='play'>1</div>"], ["More", "data", "<div class='play'>2</div>"]],
    "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"Col1"}, {"sTitle":"Col2"}, {"sTitle":"Buttons"}],
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        // retrieve the tr-element
        var element = $(nRow);
        // get id or something
        var id = element.find(".play").html();
        // insert what you want
        element.html("<button>Play: " + id + "</button>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it from the server, in my case I'm using PHP and I added two "a" tags when filling my array result query, this is my server code

```
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {                        
                    $resultado[$i] = array();
                    foreach($campos as $k => $v)
                        $resultado[$i][$k] = $v;
                    $resultado[$i]["editar"]   = '<a class="edit" href="">Editar</a>';
                    $resultado[$i]["eliminar"] = '<a class="delete" href="">Borrar</a>';
                    $i++;
                }
```

Then, my json object looks like this:

```
codigo: "1ES3" editar: "<a class="edit" href="">Editar</a>" eliminar: "<a class="delete" href="">Borrar</a>" hijo: null idioma: "ES"
```

And now I can use the "a" tags inside my dataTable.